# Is Microsoft Excel functionality patented?

Tags: patent-infringement, excel

I have been looking for open source javascript spreadsheet software that implements Excel functionality closely (down to spreadsheet functions, keyboard shortcuts) but what I find is that every other spreadsheet software has its own 'quirks' of doing the things Excel does ( different shortcut keys, different functions etc).

Is there a reason why nobody tries to replicate the Excel functionality exactly (i.e. is Excel patented?), and would it be legal for me to just fork a spreadsheet software and implement Excel's features like for like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does Microsoft have any patent related to spreadsheet?**

Yes ([Google Patent search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spreadsheet%20inassignee:microsoft&hl=en&bih=841&tbs=ptso:us,sbd:1,ptss:g&tbm=pts&source=lnt&sa=X))

But so do [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:spreadsheet%20inassignee:google&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=979&tbs=ptss:g,ptso:us&tbm=pts&source=lnt&sa=X), [Apple](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:spreadsheet%20inassignee:apple&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=979&tbs=ptss:g,ptso:us&tbm=pts&source=lnt&sa=X), Borland, SAP, IBM, etc.

**Why don't others follow Microsoft's Excel?**

This is off-topic because 1) it's not related to patent, and 2) the answers would probably be all opinion-based. Some off-topic answers:

- Excel is not open-source and it's difficult to reverse-engineer how Excel functionality works.
- Patent and **copyright** issues
- Software developer need to ensure consistency across **their** own programs
- It makes no sense to play catch-up. Better focus on what Excel doesn't do and create a better program, like Google Spreadsheet

**Is it legal for you to copy Microsoft's Excel?**

If you don't violate others' trademark, patents, and copyrights, why not?